# Взаимовидимость вершин в графе

Tags: python-3.x, графы, pygame

Подскажите друзья товарищи. Имеется сетка в виде графа, известны все координаты объектов, препятствий и всего подобного. Требуется понять, взаимовидны ли две точки? т.е. на векторе между ними не лежит никаких препятствий. Гуглить естественно  пытался, но ничего толкового для себя не нашел (в том числе и на английском). Находил только пересечение двух отрезков, это не совсем то что мне надо. В книге (Алгоритмы Справочник с примерами на С, C++, JAVA И PYTHON Джордж Хайнеман) мельком пробежался, ничего не нашел, возможно при более детальном изучении что и будет. Пускай даже если и есть какой-либо встроенный алгоритм, мне же хотелось бы понять как именно это должно работать. Буду благодарен ответившим мне людям

Comment: Не специалист, но мне кажется это можно свести к проверке общих координат графа и ибъекта. Тоесть... Граф с двумя точками можно представить, как отрезок, и, к примеру, есть еще один отрезок, в качестве второго объекта. Получаем координаты всех точек этих отрезков в множества "А" и "В". Затем проверяем эти множества на пересечение - cross=("А"|"В")-("А"^"В"). Если cross пустой - не пересекаются. Или(что может даже правильнее) использовать алгебру. Любая фигура это определенный закон/функция(в случае отрезка это линейная функция). В математике есть алгоритмы для решения пересечений фигур. Думаю.